# Incorrect 'valid from' date on UK visa

Tags: visas, uk

We had a joint application to get our visit visas to the UK and both passports were processed on the same day at the NYC consulate. Although my visa has the correct 'valid from' date my wife's validity was pushed to 10 days ahead of the intended date of arrival in the UK!Is there a way I can get this corrected?

Comment: Why is it a problem for her visa validity date to be 10 days ahead?

Comment: I think OP is using "ahead" to mean later, thus not valid until after they plan to arrive in the UK.

Comment: I read it like @brhans did.  So the OP needs to put in the dates. Marking this as unclear.  Please edit to clarify

Comment: Yes, I read "10 days ahead of the intended date of arrival" as meaning "10 days before the intended arrival". Suggest the OP edit to clarify if this is not the case.